# Using third-party scripts/applications on Laravel / MVC

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and some MVC theory, so I have been doing some research as to the best way to use third-party scripts and applications within Laravel (this question, however, certainly applies to any MVC framework). Unfortunately, I have not found an answer to my question so I thought it would be helpful to myself and others to ask it here!

Basically, I have osTicket and I wish to use it in my Laravel setup. Since osTicket is it's own, third-party application, where is the best place to upload this within my Laravel installation? My initial thought is `/public/`, but the little documentation I read on `/vendor/` makes me think it belongs there.

Would love best practice advice on where this should go...thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to actually integrate it in your app or just having a link from your app to your installation of osTicket?

Comment: I don't need to recreate the wheel and certainly don't need to break up osTicket into Laravel. I would, however, like a path from Laravel to go to my osTicket installation. I'm not quite sure (1) how to link it within routes.php (to go to, say, /support/), and where the best place for the /osticket/ files/directory to go.

Comment: It sounds like osTicket doesn't have to be hosted under the laravel application (correct me if wrong), in which case couldn't you deploy it to a separate location on server and simply define your 'support' controller to return redirects out to the osTicket app?  True you couldn't use url generation, but you could store the URL as a config setting per environment?